# Function called twice on page load or only when refreshed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, pageload

I'm having trouble with this function. For reasons uknown to me it triggers twice on page load or refresh. I tried searching for something fitting to my situation, but neither `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function())` or `window.addEventListener...` did anything but cause further hair tearing. The website is currently on localhost with Node.js if that could impact my results.

I'm pretty new to javascript so I apologize if the reasons are obvious.

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
  setTimeout(function() {
  alert("Congratulations! As our x customer, you've just got a 100% discount on your cart\n developer 
  note, fill x with specified amount from management")
      var myDiv = document.getElementById('theDiv');
      myDiv.style.display = myDiv.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
  }, 1000)
})
</script>
```

i made an alternate version, but that only triggers on page refresh. Not when coming from another page.

```
window.onload = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
  alert("Congratulations! As our x customer, you've just got a 100% discount on your cart\n developer note, fill x with specified amount from management")
  var myDiv = document.getElementById('theDiv');
  myDiv.style.display = myDiv.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
}, 1000)}
```

here is the div it's changing if that has something to do with it.

```
<div id="theDiv" style={{"display":"none"}}>Total after discount: <div 
style={{ "text-decoration": "line-through","display": "inline"}}> {getTotal().toString()}</div> {'->'} 
{priceReductionForRandomCustomer()} kr</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.

In the first code snippet, the string that you are sending to `alert()` is broken up on two lines.

The second problem is that you're including JavaScript code inside of a `<script>` tag that also has the `src=''` attribute.

Place your code inside of it's own script tag like below:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Hey</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="theDiv"></div>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
      setTimeout(function() {
          alert("Congratulations! As our x customer, you've just got a 100% discount on your cart\n developer note, fill x with specified amount from management")
          var myDiv = document.getElementById('theDiv');
          if (myDiv !== undefined) {
            myDiv.style.display = myDiv.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
          }
      }, 1000)
    })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! But it still pops up twice for me with your suggestion. I had to wrap it in a body tag cause the scipt tag was missing a parent element.

Comment: I should have mentioned that. It works in the code snippet I posted. Glad it’s working for you 

Comment: oh sorry if i was unclear, its still not working as intended. With your solution javascript threw me the error that the script tag needed a parent element.

Comment: @WorkInProgress I see. I’ll update my snippet in a few minutes.

Comment: I updated the code snippet for you. I made it into a full html5 document as a bonus.